# When I change orientation portrait to landscape, a function is restarted in Android

Tags: java, android

When I change orientation portrait to landscape (or landscaper to portrait), a function is restarted. I want the function is saved in Android. I'm making a calculator. I don't want operator buttons to be enable before number buttons is clicked. So I made a function that make operator buttons click after number buttons is clicked. However, when I clicked a number to calculate, then change orientation, the operator buttons are not enable. It's supposed to be enable. 
I mean, number click -> operator click -> number click -> equals button click -> the result is showed, this is okay. But number click -> change orientation -> operator buttons are not enable.... This is my code

[image: image of code]

Comment: Please post your code into the post, not an image of it.

Comment: thank you for your comment :)

Comment: You need to google for `android prevent orientation change`

Comment: When the screen is rotated, the activity is recreated (onCreate is called)

Comment: ... by default. But you can prevent that, if so you wish.

Comment: Okay! I also thought onCreate is called that. But I didn't know what to do. Let me google for android prevent orientation change! Thank you :)

Comment: You may also want to check out `android activity life cycle`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Go to the manifest file and set the orientation of the activity to
  either landscape or portrait.
- Save some state that your activity holds in a bundle. In OnCreate, the first thing you do is check if the bundle is null (it will be the first time). If it is not then read the bundle (it is the same one you saved) and reset all the states you saved. Save a bundle with your current state information every time at the end of OnCreate. This should fix your problem of resetting states, also allowing you to rotate the device.

This is a widely know concept and you should probably have used a search engine extensively before posting a question. Google is your friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

when you change the orientation of the device your Activity is destroyed and recreated.so you must save the state with  [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))
before the activity is destroyed and than restore it.
moreover if you want to disable orientation change than simply set `android:screenOrientation="portrait` in you Manifest.  read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) to learn how to handle runtime changes in Android.